# SEOmatic - Set the SEO tags based off of a category?

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I was wondering if there was a way I could set the SEO tags based off of a category?

eg. If a entry is in the "Marketing" category, use marketing Meta data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Just create those fields then assign them to your categories under field layout just like you would do for your sections.